# differences between 2 qr codes zxing libraries

Tags: android, zxing, difference

I have generated two QR codes from the same dataset using zxing libraries on android platform.
Is it possible to show the differences between these two using zxing libraries as well? Any other APIs that address this feature are welcome too.

Thanks.
JamesB

Comment: you code decode the QR Codes and compare the string??

Answer (score 1):

Differences? As in visual differences, you can try: http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html , as in identical files, a simple hash would work for this (MD5 or SHA).